# How do I define resources for iamrolestatements for multiple dynamodb tables in serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I want to use more than one dynamodb table in my serverless project. How do I properly define multiple resources in the iamrolestatements?

I have an example `serverless.yml`

```
service: serverless-expense-tracker
frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    EXPENSES_TABLE: "${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-expenses"
    BUDGETS_TABLE: "${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-budgets"

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.EXPENSES_TABLE}"
      # what is the best way to add the other DB as a resource

functions:
  create:
    handler: expenseTracker/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: expenseTracker/list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: expenseTracker/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    handler: expenseTracker/update.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true

  delete:
    handler: expenseTracker/delete.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    DynamoDbExpenses:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.EXPENSES_TABLE}

    DynamoDbBudgets:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.BUDGETS_TABLE}
```

You can see the area in question in the comments there.

Comment: if you have a specific question ( how to properly define multiple resources in iam role statements) then make a careful example showing what you've tried, any errors from it not working and explain exactly your intentions

Comment: Thanks @Vorsprung. I am not having any errors, but the only way I get the above linked serverless.yml to work is by defining the iam resources with a wildcard. That seems like what we engineers call a BAD IDEA. Can you help me define multiple resources in the iamrolestatements in a more, uh, encapsulated way?

Comment: Or perhaps did you mean I should not link to the yml as a gist but instead post it directly here?

Comment: I mean if you want some kind of help then ask a specific question!  See the site guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited, let me know if that isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got it!

The key was just adding a list under the key `- Resource`, but I also learned that it's better to just use the logicalIDs you use when provisioning the tables. Full example to follow:

```
service: serverless-expense-tracker

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    EXPENSES_TABLE: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" } #DynamoDbExpenses is a logicalID also used when provisioning below
    BUDGETS_TABLE: { "Ref": "DynamoDbBudgets" }

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DynamoDbExpenses", "Arn"] } #you will also see the logical IDs below where they are provisioned
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DynamoDbBudgets", "Arn"] }
functions:
  create:
    handler: expenseTracker/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses
          method: post
          cors: true

  createBudget:
    handler: expenseTracker/createBudget.createBudget
    events:
      - http:
          path: budgets
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: expenseTracker/list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses
          method: get
          cors: true

  listBudgets:
    handler: expenseTracker/listBudgets.listBudgets
    events:
      - http:
          path: budgets
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: expenseTracker/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    handler: expenseTracker/update.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true

  delete:
    handler: expenseTracker/delete.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    DynamoDbExpenses: #this is where the logicalID is defined
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1

    DynamoDbBudgets: #here too
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: when you manage two DynamoDB tables, how do you let each function to know which database need to be connected with?

Comment: In this case you will notice I've defined EXPENSES_TABLE and BUDGETS_TABLE in provider.environment. In your lambda you just reference it like so: `TableName: process.env.EXPENSES_TABLE`

Comment: but the lambda is created automatically in sls, where can I set the TableName? Do you mean in the hardler script?

Comment: Yes, in the handler script, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not set in the handler script. I know what to do now: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#environment-variables . Seems your current codes will not work, until you add environment `TABLE_NAME` for each function.

Comment: Sorry I read your question too quickly, I thought you were asking where do you use the env vars! Yes you set the names as shown above.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to put my updates since I spend time and learn a lot from this question. The currently accepted answer is not fully functioned.

What I added:

1) Make sure in your handler, there is an environment `TABLE_NAME`(or another name, you can adjust accordingly) as below, it is referring the lambda function's environment variables

```
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    Item: {
      ...
    }
  }
```

2) update `serverless.yml` to nominate table name to each function.

```
environment:
  TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" }
```

or

```
environment:
  TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbBudgets" }
```

Depend on which table the function targets.

The full `serverless.yml` is updated here:

```
service: serverless-expense-tracker

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    EXPENSES_TABLE: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" } #DynamoDbExpenses is a logicalID also used when provisioning below
    BUDGETS_TABLE: { "Ref": "DynamoDbBudgets" }

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DynamoDbExpenses", "Arn"] } #you will also see the logical IDs below where they are provisioned
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DynamoDbBudgets", "Arn"] }
functions:
  create:
    handler: expenseTracker/create.create
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses
          method: post
          cors: true

  createBudget:
    handler: expenseTracker/createBudget.createBudget
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbBudgets" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: budgets
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: expenseTracker/list.list
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses
          method: get
          cors: true

  listBudgets:
    handler: expenseTracker/listBudgets.listBudgets
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbBudgets" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: budgets
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: expenseTracker/get.get
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    handler: expenseTracker/update.update
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true

  delete:
    handler: expenseTracker/delete.delete
    environment:
      TABLE_NAME: { "Ref": "DynamoDbExpenses" }
    events:
      - http:
          path: expenses/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    DynamoDbExpenses: #this is where the logicalID is defined
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-expenses

    DynamoDbBudgets: #here too
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-budgets
```

Refer:

[serverless environment variables](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to provide access to all tables in the stack that is being deployed, you can use:

```
Resource: !Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${AWS::StackName}-*
```

This way the lambdas in your stack are limited to tables in your stack, and you won't have to update this every time you add a table.