# AWSLambdaInternal Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip InvalidParameterValueException

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless, wsl-2

Using node.js on WSL2 with Debian, I'm doing a sample project as detailed [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-create-note-api.html#configure-the-api-endpoint), and I'm currently at [this stage](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/deploy-the-apis.html).

### OLD [solved; scroll to NEW]

When I try to deploy, it gives me

```
An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceNotesId - Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- and curly braces at the beginning and the end. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException;
```

It seems to be coming from my YAML line here (I say *seems* because this is the only code in all my project files which mentions "(R|r)esource")
(Error #1)

```yaml
  environment:
    tableName: notes-sample

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:*:*" # <-- here ---
```

Yet the example shown on [the website](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-create-note-api.html#configure-the-api-endpoint) uses the same format as above, and I assume it works for them.

**Edit 1:** Also using `Resource: '*'` gives the same error.
**Edit 2:** Also using [Amazon's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html) and formatting like `Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2::"` gives the same error.
**Edit 4:** Also tried

```yaml
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:<redacted>:table/notes-sample"
```

I've also tried formatting it this way
(Error #2)

```yaml
  environment:
    tableName: { "Ref": "notes-sample" } # <-- here: change 1 ---
  # 'iamRoleStatements' defines the permission policy for the Lambda function.
  # In this case Lambda functions are granted with permissions to access DynamoDB.
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
      Resource: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["sample-note", "Arn"] } # <-- here: change 2 ---
```

however, when Serverless validates the template, it gives me the error

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [notes-sample] in the Resources block of the template
      at /home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/validateTemplate.js:20:13
```

For one, I can't find that folder on my PC, and don't know where else it might be, and two the problem still seems to be this one line of code, and I don't know what I'm missing, here.

I've looked at examples [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394171/how-do-i-define-resources-for-iamrolestatements-for-multiple-dynamodb-tables-in), [two](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia/issues/11), and tried to go through [this Japanese site](https://qiita.com/umihico/items/df2b8ce78cfe18054337), but I don't seem to be seeing what's wrong with this line.

I appreciate anyone's help.

**Edit 3:** Also using `Resource: { arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:: }` or `Resource: { arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:*:* }` gives this error

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: [/Resources/IamRoleLambdaExecution/Type/Policies/0/PolicyDocument/Statement/2/Resource/arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:*:*] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

I found out I was focusing on the wrong area and for two of my YAML files function definitions I had used [brackets] in place of {braces} from

```yaml
  update:
    handler: update.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes/[id] # <-- here --
          method: put
  delete:
    handler: delete.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes/[id] # <-- here --
          method: delete
```

to

```yaml
  update:
    handler: update.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes/{id} # <-- here --
          method: put
  delete:
    handler: delete.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes/{id} # <-- here --
          method: delete
```

**Edit 5:** I also fixed all the functions using `path: notes` to `path: notes-sample` so they match my `[environment][tableName]` declaration.

### NEW

However, now the error I'm getting is

```
An error occurred: DeleteLambdaFunction - Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException
```

I checked out [AWS Lambda deployment guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html) and [this Python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822562/serverless-uploaded-file-must-be-a-non-empty-zip), neither of which helped directly solve this.

### INFORMATION

#### serverless.yml

```yaml
# NOTE: update this with your service name
service: notes-api

# Create an optimized package for our functions 
package:
  individually: true

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle # Package our functions with Webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin # Load .env as environment variables

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: prod
  region: us-west-2
  # To load environment variables externally
  # rename env.example to .env and uncomment
  # the following line. Also, make sure to not
  # commit your .env.
  environment:
    tableName: notes-sample
  #  SAMPLE_ENV_VAR: ${env:SAMPLE_ENV_VAR}

  # 'iamRoleStatements' defines the permission policy for the Lambda function.
  # In this case Lambda functions are granted with permissions to access DynamoDB.
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:Querynpm i -D
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:082581148431:table/notes-sample"

functions:
  create:
    handler: create.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes-sample
          method: post
  get:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in get.js
    # - path: url path is /notes-sample/{id}
    # - method: GET request
    handler: get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes-sample/{id}
          method: get
  list:
    handler: list.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes-sample
          method: get
  update:
    handler: update.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes-sample/{id}
          method: put
  delete:
    handler: delete.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes-sample/{id}
          method: delete
```

delete.js

```js
import handler from "./libs/handler-lib";
import dynamoDb from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";

export const main = handler(async (event, context) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.tableName,
        Key: {
            userId: "123",
            noteId: event.pathParameters.id,
        },
    };
    await dynamoDb.delete(params);
    return { status: true };
});
```

dynamo-lib.js

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

/**
 * If DynamoDB table is in a different region,
 * make sure to set it by calling
 * AWS.config.update({ region: "my-region" });
 * before initializing the DynamoDB client
 */
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export default {
  get: (params) => client.get(params).promise(),
  put: (params) => client.put(params).promise(),
  query: (params) => client.query(params).promise(),
  update: (params) => client.update(params).promise(),
  delete: (params) => client.delete(params).promise(),
};
```

---

Old error #1

```
An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceNotesId - Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- and curly braces at the beginning and the end. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: f*******-4ae8-4**0-a822-7***********; Proxy: null).
```

Old error #2

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [notes-sample] in the Resources block of the template
      at /home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/validateTemplate.js:20:13
      at tryCatcher (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:463:21)
```